# Neglecting NaN terms in a summation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, nan

Is there a way to combine `NaN` and ordinary numbers in a different way then usually done in Fortran?

I have several summations which contains 'safe' terms, which cannot be `NaN`, and some other terms which can be `NaN`.
I would like the evaluation of the expression to neglect the addends in case they are `NaN`.

I cannot just get rid of them multiplying them times a null factor when they are `NaN` as `NaN x 0` gives `NaN` anyway.
Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is no arithmetic operation that does not propagate `NaN`. So ideas like multiplying by 0 will not work.

Your only solution is to miss out the `NaN` terms in the sum. Do that with something based on

```
IF (IEEE_IS_NAN(x))
```

If you are not using IEEE754 or are using an older standard of FORTRAN, then you can use

`IF(x .NE. x)`

which will be TRUE if and only if x is NaN.

Comment: isnan isn't a standard Fortran intrinsic. Better to use ieee_is_nan, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/692942

Comment: Also, certain compiler options will optimize away `x .ne. x`, so beware. Always test your NaN detector for each system.

Comment: @IanBush: Indeed; I haven't used FORTRAN for some time now, but in the deep and distant past I did use `IF(x .NE. x)`.

Comment: No problem - and it shows, it's officially been Fortran (lower case) for over 25 years now

Comment: ieee_is_nan may work even when not setting the options recommended for ieee_arithmetic (but this would be in part on account of that intrinsic preventing simd optimization).  Typically, the options to avoid eliding x /= x will also prevent optimization of sum reduction.

Comment: @Bathsheba would you mind giving an example of how this is used in the code? I have arrays that contain nan or very low numbers which are used as "blanks", such as -3.4000000E+38, so I would like to use SUM(myarray) and ignore nan.